# How do I grant another account permission to query for user pool client using cdk?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-cdk

I have an AWS multi account setup with several user pools in one account ("auth account") and in the other account ("app account") there is a web app that needs to query the auth account for user pool client info (the "DescribeUserPoolClient" action).

The app account is deployed using CDK and the app uses aws-sdk to query the auth account (using the DescribeUserPoolClientCommand) for information about a user pool.

How do I give access, in CDK code, to the app account to query the auth account for this information?

(The set of user pools are not known at build time, because they will be created programmatically.)

Comment: Meh, I solved it, but it turned out to be useless because aws-sdk does not allow to set accountId for the DescribeUserPoolClientCommand.

Comment: The SDK uses the current credentials for its queries. You'd grant the role it uses the required permissions and it would work.